# Why does't my pandas indexer work when I tried to filter just two values?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, mask

I tried to use a indexer to filter just two values (1 and 2) from a DataFrame, but if I check the .csv file I found some 77 values.
[image]

#My len is 15333, this is because of "77" values, the correct it will be 15286, i.e taking account just 1 and 2 values.
PD:All in 'HAD_CPOX' are int64 and I tried to use != 77.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and don't [post code as an image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Hi, please post an example of your code in text, not a photo. It really helps others to solve your question faster (and you get more replies :) Here's good examples and tips of how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look at your code and you only want to take values `HAD_CPOX==1` or `HAD_CPOX==2`, then your still have to assign your filtered df back to variable df again like this:

```
df = df[(df['HAD_CPOX'] == 1) & (df['HAD_CPOX'] == 2)]
```

You could also write:

```
df = df[df['HAD_CPOX'].isin([1, 2])
```

In your code you only have:

```
df[(df['HAD_CPOX'] == 1) & (df['HAD_CPOX'] == 2)]
```

But then your df is not assigned, so nothing is changed or filtered then from your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Sander van den Oord, I really appreciate your help. Cheers from Mexico!